# Asp net core EF Ошибка при создании миграции

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

При попытке создать миграцию пишет: Build started...
Build succeeded.
An error occurred while accessing the Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting services. Continuing without the application service provider. Error: Этот хост неизвестен.
Unable to create an object of type 'AppDbContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728
Process terminated with exit code 1.

Ошибка этот хост неизвестен вот мой файл docker-compose:

```
version: 3.9;
networks:
  Test:
    driver: bridge
services:
  composetest:
    image: composetest:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: composetest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - Test
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
  postgres_db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
      POSTGRES_DB: DB
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks: 
      - Test
    volumes:
      - post-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes: 
  post-data:
```

DbContext:

```
public class AppDbContext : DbContext
{
    public AppDbContext(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new UserConfiguration());
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
}
```

файл docker:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:7.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:7.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["COMPOSETEST/COMPOSETEST.csproj", "COMPOSETEST/"]
RUN dotnet restore "COMPOSETEST/COMPOSETEST.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/COMPOSETEST"
RUN dotnet build "COMPOSETEST.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "COMPOSETEST.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "COMPOSETEST.dll"]
```

вот файл appsetings.json:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "DB": "Server=postgres_db;port=5432;User id=postgres;password=123;database=DB"
  }
}
```

вот подключение к бд:

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
});
```

база данных Postgres контейнеры запускаются без ошибок

Comment: Этот вопрос задают очень часто. Вы по ссылке читали? Утилита миграции для своей работы должна создать экземпляр DbContext. Делается это одним из трёх способов: хост-билдер, конструктор без параметров, фабрика. Очевидно, у вас не реализован ни один из них.

Comment: P. S. Docker и ASP.NET не имеют к проблеме никакого отношения.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov да вот только я смог создать initial migration, а вот следующая миграция с ошибкой создается -_-, да и docker имеет отношение там настраивается хост который, как написано в ошибке неизвестен, добавил AppDbContext в вопрос

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том что я делал Database.Migrate() при старте проекта