# Asp net core EF ошибка при обновлении базы данных по миграции используя docker-compose

Tags: c#, asp.net, docker, asp.net-core, docker-compose

при попытке обновить базу данных возникает ошибка этот хост неизвестен

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x00002AF9): Этот хост неизвестен.
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntryOrAddressesCore(String hostName, Boolean justAddresses, AddressFamily addressFamily, Int64 startingTimestamp)
   at System.Net.Dns.GetHostAddresses(String hostNameOrAddress, AddressFamily family)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Connect(NpgsqlTimeout timeout)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.RawOpen(SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.<Open>g__OpenCore|216_1(NpgsqlConnector conn, SslMode sslMode, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken, Boolean isFirstAttempt)
   at Npgsql.Internal.NpgsqlConnector.Open(NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.UnpooledDataSource.Get(NpgsqlConnection conn, NpgsqlTimeout timeout, Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.<Open>g__OpenAsync|45_0(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection.Open()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenDbConnection(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.OpenInternal(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.RelationalConnection.Open(Boolean errorsExpected)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists(Boolean async, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL.Storage.Internal.NpgsqlDatabaseCreator.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.HistoryRepository.Exists()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Migrations.Internal.Migrator.Migrate(String targetMigration)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.UpdateDatabase(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabaseImpl(String targetMigration, String connectionString, String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.UpdateDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Этот хост неизвестен.
Process terminated with exit code 1
```

вот файл dockerCompose:

```
version: 3.9;
networks:
  Test:
    driver: bridge
services:
  composetest:
    image: composetest:latest
    restart: always
    container_name: composetest
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      - Test
    depends_on:
      - postgres_db
  postgres_db:
    container_name: postgres
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
      POSTGRES_DB: DB
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks: 
      - Test
    volumes:
      - post-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes: 
  post-data:
```

вот строка подключения

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "DB": "Server=postgres_db;port=5432;User id=postgres;password=123;database=DB"
  }
```

вот подключение бд

```
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DB");

builder.Services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseNpgsql(connectionString);
});
```

Comment: Отличие от [предыдущего](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1537885/220553) вопроса в чем? Вы там даже сами себе ответили, но нет, взяли, создали полную копию (где как по мне еще меньше информации), и просите опять помощи, без каких либо объяснений. Есть дополнения - редактируйте старый вопрос, а не создавайте новый. Ну а если тот ответ неверен, то зачем вы вводите будущих читателей, которые столкнутся с аналогичной проблемой в заблуждение? Удаляйте тогда тот ответ. Или вы думаете `.Migrate()` убрал, значит решил проблему подключения? Следующий вопрос будет про добавление, да?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Спасибо за комментарий, исправил предыдущий вопрос, где была проблема конкретно с созданием миграции, и да ошибка при создании миграции пропала после того, как я убрал Migrate() так что я никого не ввожу в заблуждение